# Visualizing a segmented toroidal surface in Matlab

Tags: matlab, 3d, plot

I have gone through the related solutions to "Visualizing a toroidal surface in Matlab" but my problem is a little different.I want to be able to visualize **segmented** toroidal surfaces arranged with vertices attached to each other.Just like a stuck of semi circles with axis along the y-axis in the x-y plane.

```
         `th = linspace( pi/2, -pi/2, 100);
         R = 1;  %or whatever radius you want
         x = -R*cos(th) + 4;
         y = -R*sin(th) + 7;
         plot(x,y); axis equal;
         hold on
         x = -R*cos(th) + 4;
         y = -R*sin(th) + 9;
         plot(x,y); axis equal;
         hold on
         x = -R*cos(th) + 4;
         y = -R*sin(th) + 11;
         plot(x,y); axis equal;
         hold on
         x = -R*cos(th) + 4;
         y = -R*sin(th) + 5;
         plot(x,y); axis equal
         hold on
         x = -R*cos(th) + 4;
         y = -R*sin(th) + 3;
         plot(x,y); axis equal
         hold on
         x = -R*cos(th) + 4;
         y = -R*sin(th) + 1;
         plot(x,y); axis equal
         hold on
         x = -R*cos(th) + 4;
         y = -R*sin(th)  -1;
         plot(x,y); axis equal
         hold on
         x = -R*cos(th) + 4;
         y = -R*sin(th)  -3;
         plot(x,y); axis equal
         hold on
         x = -R*cos(th) + 4;
         y = -R*sin(th)  -5;
         plot(x,y); axis equal
         hold on
         x = -R*cos(th) + 4;
         y = -R*sin(th) -11;
         plot(x,y); axis equal
         hold on
         x = -R*cos(th) + 4;
         y = -R*sin(th) -9;
         plot(x,y); axis equal
         hold on
         x = -R*cos(th) + 4;
         y = -R*sin(th) -7;`
         plot(x,y); axis equal`
```

Comment: could be summed up by `th = linspace( pi/2, -pi/2, 100); R = 1; 
x = -R*cos(th) + 4;
for ii = -11:2:11
    y = -R*sin(th) + ii; 
    plot(x,y); 
    axis equal; 
    hold on 
end`

Comment: Thank you.This is how I want the segmented toroidal surface to be displayed.The surface here is a toroid and i posted the code on the semi-circle just to show how i intend the plot to be.I have been stuck on this for a long time.I really need help.

Comment: The surface equation of this toroid is      G=1+sqrt(1-Cx^2*y^2);   %Cx=1/Rx; 

F=2*G*(Cx*x^2+Cy*y^2)-Cx*Cy^2*(x^2+y^2)*y^2;   %Cy=1/Ry

z=F./(G*(G+(G^2-Cx*F)));  %the function of the surface  F(x,y,z)=0